# Training RNN with error evaluation at every time step

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, prediction, backpropagation

I have a simpleRNN / LSTM that I'm trying to train on a sequential classification task using tensorflow. There is a sequence of data (300 time steps) that predicts a label at t=300.  For my task I would like for the RNN to evaluate the error at every timestep (not just at the final time point) and propagate it backwards (as figure below).

[image]

After some responses below it seems I need to do a few things: use return_sequences flag; use the TimeDistributed layer to access the output from the LSTM/RNN; and also defined a custom loss function.

```
model = Sequential()
layer1 = LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(length, 1), return_sequences=True)
model.add(layer1)
layer2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))
model.add(layer2)
    
# Define custom loss
def custom_loss(layer1):
        
    # Create a loss function
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
       # access layer1 at every time point and compute mean error
       # UNCLEAR HOW TO RUN AT EVERY TIME STEP
       err = K.mean(layer1(X) - y_true, axis=-1)
       return err
           
    # Return a function
    return loss

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss(layer), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

For now I'm a bit confused of the custom_loss function as it's not clear that how I can pass in layer1 and compute the error inside the inner most loss function.

Anyone has a suggestion or can point me to a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not easy to answer since it is not clear what you're trying to achieve (it shouldn't be the same using a FFNN or a RNN, and what works best depends definitely on the application).

Anyway, you might be confusing the *training steps* (say, the forward- and back- propagation over a minibatch of sequences) with the *"internal" steps* of the RNN. A single sequence (or a single minibatch) will always "unroll" entirely through time during the forward pass before any output is made available: only after (thus, at the end of the *training step*), you can use the predictions and compute the losses to backpropagate.

What you can do is return sequences of outputs (one y_predicted for every internal time step) including the argument `return_sequences=True` inside `SimpleRNN(...)`. This will give you a sequence of 300 predictions, each of which depends only on the past inputs with respect to the considered internal time step. You can then use the outputs that you need to compute the loss, possibly in a custom loss function.

I hope I've been clear enough. Otherwise, let me know if I can help further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Massimo.  I did indeed look at the predictions at every time step and they are bad except last few time points.  So I am looking for an NN architecture that can (i) backpropagate the error at every time step; and (ii) also keeps memory. I though an LSTM could do this - but as you say, the prediction is only evaluated after the final time step (i.e. 300 in my case).  An FFNN does (i) but has no memory.  Am I looking for an NN architecture that just doesn't exist? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Using `return_sequences=True` in the RNN layer will give you the whole output sequence - one output (tensor) for each time step, see [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/). Using the TimeDistributed layer, you'll eventually have a sequence of predictions: you need then to provide _sequences_ of labels, and Keras' loss functions will consider all of them to build the loss (averaging along the time dimension), which then automatically back-propagates through each time step.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem better now, thanks so much. I modified my question to be more specific about loss-functions and how to use TimeDistributed layer to access data.

Comment: Hello Massimo, can I ask you a related question? I'm using TimeDistributed to compute the labels and the losses separately for each time step, using a custom loss layer (model.add_loss). Should I combine my losses and return a single scalar (or rather, one per minibatch entry) or is it better to return the full sequence of losses, one for each timestep? Will the training algorithm back-propagate each loss into its own timestep in the RNN? I'm using LSTM and TimeDistributed on Keras / TF.